# Gradle error when copy to Dist Folder

Tags: gradle

Can somebody help me with this

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tsuo.png)

Sorry because I am not having enough reputation. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `error` say :

> Path too long

When you extract compressed files from the installation media, you might see a `Error 0x80010135: File path too long error`.

The error is caused when you use Windows Explorer or WinZip to extract files and it encounters a file path that exceeds the maximum character limit.

To resolve this problem, use a decompression utility such as `7-Zip`, that can handle long file paths. Otherwise, extract the files to the root directory or to the `c:/temp` directory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. :D